# How to do POST request with node.js to a php page using https-post?

Tags: php, node.js, http, post, https

All I need to do is to send POST request with node.js to a website, using https-post. Https-post it's a node module. The problem is that when I send the data to the page it should send me back the message + data, but it doesn't, is just sending me back that the page doesn't get any data.

I already tried to use http-post instead of https-post and I already tested the php page with my web browser and is working.

```
    var https = require('https');
    https.post = require('https-post');

    var data = [ "myName", "MyPass"];

https.post('https://www.mywebsite.com/page.php', { user: data[1], pass: data[2] }, function(res){
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            console.log(chunk);
    });
});
```

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Are you sure you're posting to something that actually replies? Test with `curl` or some other tool first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your scope for your `data[]` array is too large, as in you have `data[2]` but there is no `data[2]` value because arrays are zero-based. So if you change `data[1]` to `data[0]` and `data[2]` to `data[1]` your code should work.